# Laravel validator fails if response is false

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have a laravel validator on my request that is set to required, the issue is that the validation fails when the responses[0]['answer'] = false. i have a checklist in the frontend that the user submits either true or false, so i want to consider false as a actual response and should pass the validation, how can i allow that to pass validation when the responses[0]['answer'] = false

```
{
    "id": 50,
    "type": "forum",
    "responses": [
        {
            "question_id": 89,
            "answer": false
        },
        {
            "question_id": 90,
            "answer": true
        },
        {
            "question_id": 91,
            "answer": "this is a input type answer"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is how the validator looks

```
$request->validate([
 'id' => 'required',
 'responses.*.question_id' => 'required',
 'responses.*.answer_id' => 'required_if:responses.*.answer,""',
 'responses.*.answer' => 'required_if:responses.*.answer_id,"",
]);
```

i validate that

```
responses['*']['answer']
```

is required but i want to allow it even if

```
responses['*']['answer'] = false
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the issue is that the validation fails even when the request = false"?

Comment: Your question needs to be reformulated it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @KennyHorna for example responses[0]['answer'] = false which i want to consider as a valid answer and should pass the 'required' rule on validator

Comment: @Mika so for each answer, you want to accept a boolean or a string, am I right?

Comment: @KennyHorna yes

Answer (score 0):

Add the `nullable` rule to the validation string:

```
 'responses.*.answer' => 'nullable|required_if:responses.*.answer_id,"",
```